# URL Parameter Passing to Groovy Model File via JSP

Tags: jsp, groovy

I am new to Groovy and making it work with jsp's, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
<c:set var="mapData" value="<%=new GoogleMapsModel(resource)%>" />

<c:if test="${not empty param.mapSearch}">
    ${mapData.setQuery(param.mapSearch)}
</c:if>

<form name="searchForm" action="${currentPage.path}.html">
    <div class="search">
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Enter a Location..." value="${mapData.mapQueryWithSpace}" name="mapSearch"
               title="Enter a Location:" size="30">
        <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" title="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

I get an error for this:

```
${mapData.setQuery(param.mapSearch)}
```

setQuery is a method in my Model groovy file and I need to pass the mapSearch parameter to that method so that it can be set properly. Can anyone tell me what's the right procedure of passing that parameter to the method and what the method declaration for setQuery in the Model file should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get over this issue I just passed the slingRequest along with resource to the GoogleMapsModel and then used the SlingHttpServletRequest object in the model to extract the parameters.